# Error CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TModel>.Model'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, telerik

i'm having issues trying to implement a forloop in a view using a ViewModel.

I have this ViewModel

```
public class EventDashboard
{
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}

    public ICollection<FighterDetails> FightersFees{ get; set; }

    public void LoadFighterDetails(int eventId, int fighterId, aContext ac, bContext bc){

        Fighters fighter = ac
            .Fighters
            .Include(npo => npo.FighterAddress)
            .FirstOrDefault(npo => npo.FighterId== fighterId);

        this.Name = fighter.Name;
                    this.Email = fighter.Email;
                    this.Phone = fighter.Phone;

        LoadFees(bc, fighterId);
    }

    public void LoadFees(bContext bc, int fighterId)
    {
                 var fees = bc.Fees.Where(f => f.fighterId == fighterId);
                 FightersFees = new List<FighterDetails>();

                 foreach(var f in fees){
                    this.FightersFees.Add(new FighterDetails{
                             //fill the properties
                       });
                 }
            }
    }

public class FighterDetails
{
    public string FighterName { get; set; }
    public int fighterId { get; set; }
    public decimal FighterFee { get; set; }
}
```

on my view:

```
        <% foreach( var d in Model.Fighters){ %>
        <%} %>
```

but it keeps pushing out that error (on subject). wonder why it happens on viewmodels. any thoughts on how to help me understand this error is very much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

- added the rest of the code
- and the project is currently using ef 4.0. not sure if that will be relevant.

Comment: Are you sure that´s the line where the error occurs? It seems like you declare another variable named `Model` somewhere in your view.

Comment: yeah same line. and even if i try to put it on a telerik grid it gives me that error.

Comment: Can you include more code from your view?

Comment: got the answer boss. thanks for the reply. (included it in the post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you can't use the "Model" in declaring something if you already declared it??

Well, to explain it better, this is what helped me.
[Model conflicts with declaration](http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2011/01/cs0135-model-conflicts-with-declaration.html)

i was actually declaring Model on the first few edit boxes.
eg. `<%: Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FighterName)%>`

and then call it again on the foreach. The first time you declare it causes that error.

Comment: Awesome -- thanks!  I had the same exact problem.  Seems like Visual Studio should flag the problem, not the side effect.  (I understand that in this case, _I_ am the problem -- but I like VS to save me from myself.)